# GAE: Changing the value of one entity when another entity's value changes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

So let's say I have two datastore models:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    has_dog = ndb.BooleanProperty(default = False)

class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty() # key of associated Author entity
```

When a *Book* entity is created, its `author_key` is assigned the key of the *Author* entity. Now, I can query a list of books per author like this:

```
books_per_author = Book.query(Book.author_key == author_key).fetch()
```

...and then render them on the jinja template like this:

```
{% for book in books_per_author %}
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

But what if I want to also display the Author's `has_dog` value in this same template? Maybe I can normalize the data into the `Book` entity like this:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    author_has_dog = ndb.BooleanProperty() # get this value from Author entity before book.put() happens
```

So now, when we create a Book entity, we just grab the Author's `has_dog` value and save it within the Book's `author_has_dog` property. Problem solved, and we can then do this:

```
{% for book in books_per_author %}
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
    <div>Has dog: {{book.author_has_dog}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Question:** Now, what if we suddenly change the value of `has_dog` inside the `Author` entity? How do we efficiently change the `author_has_dog` value inside many `Book` entities associated with that author?

**Edited** to include `NewBook` handler:

```
class NewBook(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        author_key = self.get_author_key()
        self.render('booklist-per-author.html', title = title, author_key = author_key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better option is to just reference the author from the book:

```html
{% for book in books_per_author %}
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
    <div>Has dog: {{book.author_key.get().has_dog}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and no update handling is required.

You may want to trigger a pre-fetch on the author; in your view code, before you render your template, call:

```
book.author_key.get_async()
```

to kick of an asynchronous fetch for the author object, by the time your template is being rendered it may already have arrived.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters. This is exactly what I am looking for. However, I am unfamiliar with the use of `_async` (I just know the basic theory behind it). If it is not too much trouble, could you explain how `book.author_key.bet_async()` would fit into my code? I have edited the question to include the `NewBook` handler. Thank you so much in any case.

Comment: @haopei: if you are starting out with an author key, you may as well prefetch that; call `author_key.get_async()`. The call returns immediately, and just instructs the app engine to go ahead and fetch the data because you'll want to access it later. If you then try to access that same key again with `.get()` it'll use the pre-fetched data or join the already running async fetch. It's like sending a runner ahead to go start the grocery shopping while you drop by the book store, when you get to the super market the runner has already done some or all of the shopping for you.

Comment: let's assume that the `Author` model here also included other properties like `age`, `date_of_birth` and `gender`. In order to retrieve all of these, I can do individual calls like `book.author_key.get().gender` for all properties. Does this mean that I am spending a datastore read for each `get()`? I am concerned about scalability here.

Comment: @haopei: no, those calls will reuse cached data. You can always store the author in a local variable first, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pre_put function](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks), which automatically runs when you `put()` an author entity:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    has_dog = ndb.BooleanProperty(default = False)

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        # update books ...
        books = Book.query(Book.author_key == author_key).fetch()
        for book in books:
            book.author_has_dog = self.has_dog
        ndb.put_multi(books)
```

This doesn't scale too well if authors tend to have a lot of books though, so you may wish to offload to a cron job which periodically checks for inconsistencies, however this allows for the potential for data to become stale.

Alternatively, just look up to the author each time, as Martjn mentions in his answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gwyn. You're right - this one is not very scaleable :) You have brought my attention to the `pre_put` function which looks useful for many other things I'm trying to do.